# Using facebook share icon instead of share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

How can I use facebook share icon instead of button?

I am using this code :

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-caption='Testing Facebook Share' data-href="www.google.com" data-type="icon" data-width="200"></div>
```

Am I doing correct. The image displaying is too small. Even data-width doesn't works.

What is the correct way to do it? or increase the size of the icon?

Comment: Any thought on this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found out some workaround on this. Now the code looks like :

`<a style="margin-right: 20px;" href="facebook.com/share.php?u=www.google.com&t=Title"; onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=365,width=600');retur‌​n false;"><img src="/images/FB.png" alt="Facebook" width="55" height="55"/></a>`

Now, after clicking on share button in share dialogue, how should I handle some boolean variable in my app?